# PHP GET много почти одинаковых полей

Tags: php, html

есть проблема, И так из-за того что я не смог правильно сформировать вопрос не смог найти в гугле решения.
Так вот есть форма в которой динамически могут изменятся количество чекбоксов к примеру на выходе такое получим $_GET['checkbox_1'] но их может быть и до $_GET['checkbox_100'] и больше не писать же проверку каждого до пары тысяч)
можно ли через фореч или вайл запустить поиск по 'checkbox_*' чтобы оно искало по части тега без цифры и в цикле делать проверку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Делаем вид что мы передали эти 2 чек бокса
$_GET['checkbox_1'] = 11;
$_GET['checkbox_2'] = 22;

// Обычная проверка
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if (mb_substr($key, 0, 9) == 'checkbox_') {
        echo $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Если нужно чтоб прям "checkbox_[число]"
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if (mb_substr($key, 0, 9) == 'checkbox_') {
        $number = mb_substr($key, 9);
        if (intval($number) == $number) {
            echo $number . '-' . $value . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: на сколько я вижу идет проверка на то что оно будет искать до тех пор пока есть значения верно?
если да то как быть если выделены чекбокс к примеру 1 и 15?

Comment: Можно же проще? `$count = 1; while (isset($_GET['checkbox_' . $count])) {$count++ ****`

Comment: ну на выходе получим $_GET['checkbox_1'] и $_GET['checkbox_15'] только вот оно после первого увидит что второго нету и прекратит вайл

Comment: @secret_coder согласен, вариант 2

Comment: @Manitikyl да это же прям мой ответ=) За исключением проверки ключа=)

Comment: хах сейчас буду тестировать этот вариант)) 
огромное спасибо за ответы)

Comment: @Walfter сорян, не видел :<

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxArray[]" />
```

пройти по всем полям и проверь, то что нужно. Получается массив полей типа `checkbox`.

---

На стороне сервера, проверяете, что `isset($_POST['checkboxArray'])` (такому кол-ву полей уже не подойдет *$_GET*) и пройти можно `foreach` например.

---

**UPD:**

```
// Проверка
if(isset($_POST['checkboxArray'])){

    $arCheckboxes = $_POST['checkboxArray'];
    // Подсчет элементов
    $size = count($arCheckboxes);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
         // your code goes here...
         // Проход по элементам
         echo $arCheckboxes[$i];
    }    
}
```

Comment: В принципе да но я лично для себя хочу узнать можно ли осуществлять поиск именно по части тега

Comment: @secret_coder можно.

Comment: можно узнать как?

Comment: @secret_coder создать с помощь JS, элементы и отправить на сервер? с пройти по ним так как вы описали.

Comment: @secret_coder я на самом деле запутался, вы что хотите-то? опишите еще раз и другими словами.

Comment: хочу узнать как сделать поиск по всем $_GET['checkbox_']) которые поступили и сделать проверку в цыкле